# Magento 2: Product disappeared from frontend when I try to edit it

Tags: magento2, product, reindex

I am facing much trouble issue in Magento 2.

I edited a bundle product and assign some simple product to it, product disappeared from frontend and only shows product image in detail page.

I have also assigned that bundle product to a specific category but when I try to access category page, it shows "There are no product matching the selection".

I have reindex the website again and again but no solution.

I don't know what is causing this issue. Can somebody help?

Comment: check associated product quantities and also is it in stock or not!

Comment: I don't think it is the issue. All is fine in this case. I was working on product detail page early but when I try to edit this product in backend and save and referesh the product detail page, all is gone except image. Category is also not showing that product.